# What happened to my rose plants?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care, roses

The leaves of my rose plant is turning yellow. The young buds are turning brown. Lately the budding ends are drying up.

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] |

I water them everyday. Why they are drying up? I can't understand what went wrong. Is there a way to get flowers again?

Comment: I suggest putting the water on the soil and not wetting the plants . wet leaves can promote fungus which may be the problem.

Comment: Thanks for responding, okay, I shall try some anti-fungal spray. But what about the yellow leaves, is it too because of fungus?

Answer (score 1):

Growth of rose plants depends on a number of factors including:

- Sunlight
- Nutrition
- Watering
- Pests
- Diseases/fungus

Seems like in your case quite a few of these factors are in play

Fungus is one, growth of fungus indicates high humidity or low sunlight, even both, ensure your plant is getting at least 4-8 hours of sunlight and has enough nutrition. Add a good organic rose fertilizer.